# Inconsistent behaviour of object method 'hasOwnProperty'

Tags: javascript, json, object, methods, ecmascript-5

**Problem Statement :**

If object having same `property` name as JavaScript predefined `method` have. It fails to execute and gives below error.

> Uncaught TypeError: obj.hasOwnProperty is not a function

**Code :**

```js
var obj1 = {
  "key1":"value1",
  "key2":"value2"
}

console.log(obj1.hasOwnProperty('key2')); // true

var obj2 = {
  "key1":"value1",
  "key2":"value2",
  "hasOwnProperty": "value3"
}

console.log(obj2.hasOwnProperty('key2')); // Uncaught TypeError: obj.hasOwnProperty is not a function
```

**Code Explanation :**

In above code snippet I am trying to check if the `key` of an `object` exist or not.

Hence, in first `console` statement it returns `true` as `obj1` having property named as `key2` but it fails when new property with named as `"hasOwnProperty": "value3"` added in to the object.

As we know using of the JavaScript object method name as an object `property` is not a good practice but API team do not know about the JavaScript predefined methods. Hence, they can send it in the API response.

**Expectation :**

I want to check using `hasOwnProperty()` method that `key2` exist in `obj2` or not which having `hasOwnProperty` property in it.

Comment: That's not inconsistent, that's very consistent, if you're overridding a method, that's what you'll get ...

Comment: Because JS finds own properties `->` prototype properties `->` and so on until get some match.  So, JS has found `hasOwnProperty` as an Own Property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get around that by using the prototype method and `call` to pass your object as first argument:

```js
var obj2 = {
  "key1":"value1",
  "key2":"value2",
  "hasOwnProperty": "value3"
}

console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj2, 'key2'));
```

A bit shorter is using `{}` instead of `Object.prototype`, but that incurs some miniscule overhead:

```
{}.hasOwnProperty.call(obj2, 'key2')
```

#### Remark

The object you use to get access to the `hasOwnProperty` property really is irrelevant, as long as it inherits from `Object.prototype`. So you can make things look complicated by using some other unrelated (or seemingly related) object:

```
Math.hasOwnProperty.call(obj2, 'key2')

Function.hasOwnProperty.call(obj2, 'key2')

obj1.hasOwnProperty.call(obj2, 'key2')

"".hasOwnProperty.call(obj2, 'key2')

NaN.hasOwnProperty.call(obj2, 'key2')

JSON.hasOwnProperty.call(obj2, 'key2')

Object.hasOwnProperty.call(obj2, 'key2')
```

... etc. ;-)

Comment: or even `Object.hasOwnProperty` without the overhead

Comment: Yes, but that still has some overhead, as (in theory) JS has to look up the prototype of `Object`, as `Object` itself does not have that property.

Comment: Sorry, yes.  I meant the overhead of not creating a new Object.  I think most JS Engines now cache the prototype chain.

Comment: Just out of curiosity I did a jsPerf on different methods for getting at `hasOwnProperty`, in a nutshell, it appears there is no performance difference.  Every time I run the jsPerf on Chrome, & Firefox different versions are the fastest.  The only consistent result is that getting direct from the object is is the slowest.   https://jsperf.com/getownproperty-prototype-chain/1

Comment: Actually scrub that last comment,.  Firefox is actually pretty consistent with the fastest option, and that's a local var snapshot,.. Chrome is all over the place, really inconsistent.  Also another pro for Firefox is much faster,..  On my machine  29,964 ops per sec, compared with Chromes 15,740, IOW; Firefox is nearly twice as fast as Chorme.. Oh!!!,  is Google's V8 engine getting left behind?..